Independence Axiom and Expected Utility Theorem Proof
In my micro class we covered the proof of the existence of a Von Neumann–Morgenstern utility representation of preferences $\succeq$ over a set of lotteries $\Delta(Z)$ - where $Z$ is some finite outcome space - when preferences are rational, continuous, and satisfy the independence axiom. The independence axiom states that for $L,L',L''\in \Delta(Z)$, for each $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $$L\succeq L' \iff \alpha L+(1-\alpha)L'' \succeq \alpha L'+(1-\alpha )L''$$
In proving existence, we showed there existed two lotteries $L_B,L_W\in \Delta(Z)$ such that $L_B \succeq L \succeq L_W$ for all $L\in \Delta(Z)$. Ignoring the trivial case when $L_B\sim L_W$, we defined $U(L_B)=1$ and $U(L_W)=0$ as the first step of constructing our vNM representation. We then proved that by continuity of preferences, for each $L\in \Delta(Z),\exists !\alpha \in[0,1]$ such that $L\sim \alpha L_B+(1-\alpha)L_W$. Then, for each outcome $z\in Z$, we defined $U([z])=\alpha_z$, where $\alpha_z$ is such that $[z]\sim \alpha_z L_B +(1-\alpha)L_W$ and $[z]$ is the degenerate lottery on $z$.
The step I don't understand is the following. For any lottery $L\in \Delta(Z)$, we can represent it as a compound lottery $L\sim\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^L[z_i]$ where $p_i^L$ is the probability of outcome $z_i$ in the lottery $L$. Additionally, $[z]\sim u(z)L_B+(1-u(z))L_W$. From here, my professor concludes that by independence $$L\sim \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^L u(z_i)\right)L_B+\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^L u(z_i)\right)L_W$$ I do not understand how this conclusion is reached. This looks like we have just inserted $[z]=u(z)L_B+(1-u(z))L_W$  into the compound representation of $L$, but I can't see how it is following from independence.
Could someone explain how to get this result just using the definition of independence?

I am thinking about approaching the problem like this. Notice that $$L\sim\sum_{i=1}^np_i^L[z_i]=p_1^L[z_1]+(1-p_1^L)\sum_{j=2}^n \frac{p_j^L}{1-p_1^L} [z_j]$$ and that $\tilde{L}=\sum_{j=2}^n \frac{p_j^L}{1-p_1^L} [z_j]$ is a lottery itself since $0\leq \frac{p_j^L}{1-p_1^L}=\frac{p_j^L}{\sum_{i=2}^np_i^L}\leq 1$ and $\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{p_j^L}{1-p_1^L}=1$. Since $[z_1]\sim u(z_1)L_B+(1-u(z_1))L_W$, by independence, $$p_1^L[z_1]+(1-p_1)\tilde{L}\sim p_1^Lu(z_1)L_B+(p_1^L-p_1^Lu(z_1))L_W+\tilde{L}$$ therefore $$L\sim p_1^Lu(z_1)L_B+(p_1^L-p_1^Lu(z_1))L_W+\sum_{j=2}^n \frac{p_j^L}{1-p_1^L} [z_j]$$ I think we can continue iteratively, first taking the $[z_2]$ element out of the sum, then $[z_3]$, etc., but I can't quite figure out how to get the maths to work.

Let us first show that the function $u$ is linear in the sense that for all lotteries $L$ and $L'$ and all $\alpha \in [0,1]$: $u(\alpha L + (1-\alpha) L') = \alpha u(L) + (1-\alpha) u(L')$.
Let $L \sim a L_B + (1-a) L_W$ and $L' \sim b L_B + (1-b) L_W$
Then using independence on $L \sim a L_B + (1-a) L_W$ together with $L'$ gives
$$
\alpha L+ (1-\alpha) L' \sim \alpha \underbrace{[a L_B + (1-a) L_W]}_{=L''} + (1- \alpha) L'. \tag{1}
$$
Next, using independence on $L' \sim b L_B + (1-b) L_W$ with the lottery $L''$ gives:
$$
\alpha L'' + (1- \alpha) L' \sim \alpha \underbrace{L''}_{=a L_B + (1-a) L_W} + (1-\alpha)[b L_B + (1-b) L_W]. \tag{2}
$$
The lottery on the right hand side equals:
$$
(\alpha a + (1-\alpha) b) L_B + (\alpha (1-a) + (1-\alpha)(1- b)) L_B.
$$
By transitivity (1) and (2) gives,
$$
\alpha L + (1-\alpha) L' \sim (\alpha a + (1-\alpha) b) L_B + (\alpha(1-a) + (1-\alpha)(1-b)) L_B.
$$
Replacing $a$ by $u(L)$ and $b$ by $u(L')$ gives that:
$$
u(\alpha L + (1-\alpha) L) = \alpha u(L) + (1-\alpha) u(L').
$$
Now to finish the proof, let $L = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i z_i$. Let us show by induction on $n$ that $u(L) = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i u(z_i)$. If $n = 1$ then $L = z_1$ so $u(L) = u(z_1)$ which gives the base case.
Now for the induction step, assume that $L = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} p_i z_i$. Define $L' = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{p_i}{(1 - p_{n+1})} z_i$.
By induction, $u(L') = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{p_i}{(1 - p_{n+1})} u(z_i)$. Also,
$$
L = p_{n+1} z_{n+1} + (1-p_{n+1}) L' 
$$
So using the first part of the proof and the induction hypothesis (linarity of $u$):
$$
\begin{align*}
u(L) &= u(p_{n+1} z_{n+1} + (1-p_{n+1}) L'),\\
&= p_{n+1} u(z_{n+1}) + (1-p_{n+1}) u(L'),\\
&= p_{n+1} u(z_{n+1}) + \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i u(z_i),\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} p_i u(z_i).
\end{align*}
$$

Thank you! I hadn't thought to prove the linearity of $u$, but I can see that makes the approach much clearer. Thanks again!
